# How to set html content in Moodialog

Tags: javascript, mootools

I've just downloaded Moodialog, a Mootools plugin for dialog, but I have a problem.

If `content` is set via parameters it will be text and not HTML.

Can you help me change the function to accept HTML?

I suppose that this is the code to be edit.

```
  setContent: function(){
      var content = Array.from(arguments);
      if (content.length == 1) content = content[0];

      this.content.empty();

      var type = typeOf(content);
      if (['string', 'number'].contains(type)) this.content.set('text', content);
      else this.content.adopt(content);

      return this;
  },
```

I tried to edit `text` in `html`, but it will not work.

Thanks for help (and sorry for my bad english).

Comment: when requesting help on particular plugins, please link to the plugin itself and best create a http://www.jsfiddle.net/ example (use assets on left to bring in the plugin). looking at this, content can be a html collection or string. if you change `this.content.set("text"` to `"html"` and it fails, then it probably is not being run because of wrong type. what is the function run with - console.log the content array.

Answer (score 1):

The idea was push people to use the `Element` type, instead of using pieces html code in your javascript. If you don't want to modify your code, you can always use:

```
dialog.setContent(new Element('div', {html: '<p>html code</p>'}));
```